# Add Host to Service Bus Farm' Failed & Service Bus Message Broker Service stuck on Starting mode

Tags: 2016, service-bus, workflow-manager-farm

when I install & Configure WF Farm in one of SP 2016 APP Server I am facing issue, I created new Farm and WF Manager Configuration wizard fails at 'Add Host to Service Bus Farm'
I enabled TlS 1.0,1.1,1.2 already before starting the wizard.
and Service Bus Message Broker Service in Starting state.

[image]

In Event Viewer below errors:

Faulting application name: Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.exe, version: 2.0.50926.9, time stamp: 0x5a0a1de1
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0x80131623
Fault offset: 0x00007ff955393102
Faulting process id: 0x2074
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7815c0d76f752
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1\Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 16a5f355-4152-4727-8e9a-29f4498210e6
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Application: Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Failed to start Service Bus Broker Service.
Stack:
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.MessageBroker.Backend.OnStart(System.String[])
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the WFM config wizard with a account that is local administrator? Also this accounts needs to be have "Log on as Service" and "Log on as Batch" permission

Comment: yes it has above permissions.